# haskell, map two lists adding each element of one with each of the other list

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

There's a function given in list-comprehension style

```
f1 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f1 xs ys = [ x+y | x <- xs, y <-ys ]
```

That's not that complicated.
Example output:

> *Main> f2 [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]
>   [6,7,8,9,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,9,10,11,12]

The task is to transform this and several other functions, only using `map`, `filter` and `concat`.
There is no problem to the other functions but I don't get how to work out the nested `map` here.
Each element of the first list is to be added to each element in the other list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ x+y | x <- xs, y <-ys ]
```

is the same as

```
do {x <- xs; y <- ys; return (x + y)}
```

is the same as

```
xs >>= \x -> ys >>= \y -> return (x + y)
```

`>>=` is called bind. What is being used here is the famous list monad. For lists, return is defined as `return x = [x]` and bind is defined as `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs`, and `concatMap` is, as the name suggests, simply a composition of `concat` and `map`.

The idea behind the list monad is that with `x <- xs`, you nondeterministically choose some arbitrary element of the list, then do some computation with it and in the end, you get a list of all the possible results you can get. So in your example,

```
do {x <- xs; y <- ys; return (x + y)}
```

chooses `x` and `y` nondeterministically from `xs` and `ys`, respectively, and you get a list of all possible results.

I will now leave it to you to use this knowledge to transform your list comprehension to an expression that uses only `map` and `concat`.

As for `filter`, a condition `b` in a list comprehensions is translated to `guard b` in the list monad, which can be expressed with `filter` if you want a non-monadic expression.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than directly giving the solution to this homework, I'll explain it in more general terms. You might not understand most of it right now, but should at least be able to pick out what you need!

`map` is just a specialised version (for the list functor) of the `Functor` method of "promoting" a function to a functor-function:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a->b) -> f a->f b
```

Now, lists are a particularly powerful kind of functor: an *applicative* functor, even a monad. `Applicative` confuses many programmers, but your example is a really good fit:

> Prelude> :m +Control.Applicative
>   Prelude Control.Applicative> let f1 xs ys = (+) <‌$> xs <‌*> ys
>   Prelude Control.Applicative> :t f1
>   f1 :: (Num b, Applicative f) => f b -> f b -> f b
>   Prelude Control.Applicative> f1 [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]
>   [6,7,8,9,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,9,10,11,12]

Of course you could also write simply

> Prelude Control.Applicative> (+) <‌$> [1,2,3,4] <*> [5,6,7,8]
>   [6,7,8,9,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,9,10,11,12]

Looks simple enough, but how does this work? What's confusing about the `Applicative` class is that you keep plunging curried functions into the functor, evaluate them partially *in there*, and somehow retrieve the result from outside. With monad's you don't do that, so they're a bit simpler to grasp. Using only the `Monad` type class, the example can also be done (`Monad` is strictly sronger than `Applicative`).

Haskell lists comprehensions are really just syntactic sugar for monad operations!

```
                   [ x+y | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
```

is sugar for

```
                   xs >>= \x -> ys >>= \y -> return (x+y)
```

or with extra parentheses:

```
                   xs >>= ( \x -> ( ys >>= ( \y -> return (x+y) ) ) )
```

well, this you can transform to something with only `map` and `concat` by using these rules:

- `ys >>= (\y -> return (f y))` is the same as `map f ys`.
- `zs >>= (\z -> g z)` is the same as `concat (map g zs)`.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be this:

```
f1 xs ys = concat $ map (\x -> map (\y -> x + y) ys) xs
```

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> f1 [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]
[6,7,8,9,7,8,9,10,8,9,10,11,9,10,11,12]
```

Comment: You could also reduce this to `concat $ map (\x -> map (+x) ys) xs`

Answer (score 0):

A generic list comprehension has the form

```
[ e | qual1 , qual2 , ... , qualN ]
```

where `e` is an expression, and `qual` are qualifiers. Qualifiers can be of three forms: generators (`x<-list`), boolean guards (`x/=0`), and local declarations (`let x = ...` ). Since you only use generators, I will focus on those.

According to the [Haskell definition](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11), list comprehesions can be translated as follows

```
[ e | x<-l , quals ] = concat $ map (\x -> [ e | quals ]) l
[ e | ]              = [ e ]  -- singleton list
```

so you can apply these to `[ x+y | x <- xs, y <-ys ]` and obtain the solution (which is essentially the one in Sibi's answer).